# base64 coded text to readable text in power bi

Tags: text, powerbi, base64

Could you please help to decode base 64 column  to text?

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Lines.FromBinary(Binary.FromText([Column1],BinaryEncoding.Base64), null, null, 1252){0})
```

Comment: Please adjust the tagging of your question

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, add a new calculated column using:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.FromBinary(Binary.FromText([MyBase64Column], BinaryEncoding.Base64)))
```